# The probability of two elements generating a finite abelian group.

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a Group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p^s\mathbb{Z}$, where $p$ is prime number and $r$ and $s$ are positive integers. What is the probability that two random elements $P,Q \in G$ generate the Group? According to this paper

https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-48000-6_9

on page 10 the answer is

$\frac{\varphi(p^r) \varphi(p^s)}{p^{r+s}},$

where $\varphi$ is the Euler function. This is equal to $(1-\frac{1}{p})^2$. Unfortunately there is no explanation for this. I see the connection to the Euler function (For a cyclic Group, the answer is easy), but I have no idea to answer the  question in the upper case. Can someone help?

I found a paper

[https://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/sim.pdf](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Epak/papers/sim.pdf)

that proves (I think), that if $(P,Q)$ is a ordered pair, then the probability that $\langle P,Q \rangle = G$ is $(1-\frac{1}{p})(1-\frac{1}{p^2})$. My problem is slightly different, because I'm interested in set $\{P,Q \}$ (with cardinality one or two), not in ordered pairs.

Comment: I don't understand. In what sense is a random ordered pair different from a random unordered pair here? How are you sampling $\{P,Q\}$? Anyway, ignoring this, the Frattini subgroup of an abelian $p$-group $G$ being just $G^p$, two elements generate $C_{p^r} \times C_{p^s}$ iff their images in the quotient group $C_p \times C_p$ generate that group, and we can easily list the subgroups of $C_p \times C_p$ so this is easier.

Comment: The usual way of choosing $P$ and $Q$ would be to choose a random element $P$ and then a random element $Q$, in which case you are choosing a random ordered pair $(P,Q)$ rather than a random unordered pair, which I can see is not quite the same thing, but would not be the natural way of proceeding. For a random ordered pair the answer is indeed $(1-1/p)(1-1/p^2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Its in fact the same problem and with Sean Eberhards hints its easy to solve. I'm new here. Should i write down a complete solution?